# responsive solution for search button beside input form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

does anyone have an idea to have this code responsive ? it looks quite good at chrome (1920x1080) but bad on mobile displays:

```html
<form action="searchResult.php" method="post" id="result">
  <input type="submit" style="float: right;/* width: 60px; */height: 65px;border-radius: 100px;/* border-left-style: double; */font-size: 25px;/* margin-top: 10px; *//* position: relative; */border: 2px solid #2B2E34;border-left-style: hidden;border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;border-top-left-radius: 20px;"
  value="Suchen">
  <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
    <input type="text" class="input" name="searchrestaurant" id="searchfieldRestaurant" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="PLZ, Ort">
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Aesthetics are generally a very subjective matter. However, responsive is usually achieved either using bootstrap or perhaps using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) (not yet widely implemented)

Answer (score 2):

To handle all devices it would be better to use a framework like Bootstrap or Foundation.

if you want specific design on specific device or ratio you have to use [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a specified css for different screen sizes like so

```
/* Small devices (tablets and phones, 768px and below) */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .display-block-on-mobile {
     display: block;
   }
}
```

use `min-width` and `max-width` to specify which sizes to affect

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [Bootsrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

But this code will show you the concept they use. You have to think in term of `%` and `em` instead of `px`.

(To understand you have to resize the window under 400px)

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px; /* Set default font-size */
}
body {
  margin: 0; /* Reset margin to 0 */
}
.row { 
  position: absolute; /* Set relative width to this */
  width: 100%;
}
.col {
  float: left; /* All `.col` are float left */
}
.col:nth-child(1) {
  width: 75%; /* The first col is 75% */
}
.col:nth-child(2) {
  width: 25%; /* The second col is 25% */
}
/* Media query, code effect only when window is under 600px */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Mobile need bigger font size */
  body {
    font-size: 1.2em;      
  }
  /* Both .col are 100% */
  .col:nth-child(1), .col:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100%; 
  }
}
/* Input take 100% of the parent .col */
input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;  
}
input[type="text"] {
  line-height: 1.5em;      
}
input[type="button"] {
  font-size: 1.2em;      
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="button" value="Button"/>
  <div>
</div>
```